# Set up pandas as pd alias in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently started using vscode for python. I have a problem using alias. When i try to use import pandas as pd, it gives me intelligence options like pandas, pdb,pudb. I have no idea why its doing that and pd doesn't work.

Any idea on how to make alias work in vscode

Comment: because `pdb` and `pudb` also contain the chars `p` and `d` and you have them somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: How do i make this work? THis is what i have on my python path--"pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that problem you can use `;` then press enter it should work

```
import numpy as pd;
```

Comment: or press ESC to kill intellisence