# How to stop VSCode Intellisense in `import X as y` statements?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, alias, intellisense

In VS Code when you import a module as an alias Intellisense suggests auto-completions, which appear to be Python path binaries.

For example, when I try and `import pandas as pd` I get `pdb` and `pudb` as suggestions:

[image: import pandas as pd pdb pudb]

which, if I instinctively press enter on, results in `import pandas as import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, an error:

[image: import pandas as import pdb; pdb.set_trace()]

It seems to me that there should be no Intellisense at all for aliases because there is no "correct" alias for an imported library, and this is just a bug.

My question is, is there a way to disable Intellisense for cases like this?

I could press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or add a `;` and it will go away. I could also use a plain text editor, instead of an IDE.

Incidentally, someone tried to ask this question earlier but it was not phrased clearly and was closed [Set up pandas as pd alias in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248890/set-up-pandas-as-pd-alias-in-vscode)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, is there a way to disable Intellisense for cases like this?

Not that I am aware of. Maybe raise an issue on Github?

#### Workaround:

These are the two settings that I use to get rid of annoying autocompletion except for tab-completion:

```json
{
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
}
```